# Amazon S3 life cycle rule for folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My application uses Amazon S3 to store some files, uploaded by customer. I want to set a rule that automatically should watch for particular folder's content, specifically - to delete files, that were created month ago. Is that possible?

Comment: I did this using a schedule job which go and get files older than a specific date on S3 and then delete them.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Yes** you can set a rule that automatically should watch for particular folder's content, specifically - to delete files, that were created month ago.

**For this go to 'lifecycle policy' -> 'Expiration'. In 'Expiration' section set prefix as the path to files that you want to apply your rule.**

For example: If I want to apply rule to '*fileA.txt*' in folder '*myFolder*' in bucket '*myBucket*'. Then I should set prefix as '*myFolder/*'.

> Amazon S3 has a flat structure with no hierarchy like you would see in a typical file system. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this by using key name prefixes for objects.

For more info refer [FolderOperations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html)

You can also do it with CloudFormation rules.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: DeleteRule
            Prefix: myFolder/
            Status: Enabled
            ExpirationInDays: 31
Outputs:
  BucketName:
    Value: !Ref S3Bucket
    Description: Name of the sample Amazon S3 bucket with a lifecycle configuration.
```

For moe info see [lifecycle rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule.html).

Comment: The prefix should not contain an asterisk. S3 lifecycle rules doe not treat asterisk as a wildcard, but rather as a literal. Using prefix 'myFolder/*' would match objects such as myFolder/*fileAt.txt.

Comment: lets say I put a rule to prefix "logs/" and dont have any contents inside, and my day of expiration is set to 1 day. 
After 1 day, does logs folder get deleted? or it only applies to objects created inside that prefix, and they get deleted after 1 day of each respective object file creation?

Comment: @Rakesh no, logs/ folder  is not deleted in your example. Nothing happens.
To delete that folder you would need to target the parent folder. Relevant link with examples:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html#lifecycle-config-ex1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to delete/expire and transition the objects to lower cost storage classes in AWS to save cost. You can find it under
`S3 - [Your_Folder] - Management - Create Lifecycle rule`

provide folder that you want to perform the action in prefix section as "folder/"

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can setup an S3 lifecycle policy that will make S3 automatically delete all files older than X days: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html

Comment: And assuming that by 'folder' the OP means an S3 prefix then he'd need to specify a lifecycle configuration rule that targets only that prefix. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#intro-lifecycle-rules-prefix.

Comment: @Mircea this is called a *lifecycle policy*, not a *bucket policy* (which has to do with access permissions).