# AWS S3 Lifecycle policy delete objects in a folder, but folder got deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have setup AWS S3 Lifecycle policy to delete objects in a folder after 1 day.
However, when the folder has no object, the folder itself got deleted after 1 day as it expired. I understand that in S3 a folder is considered as an object and not a folder.

How can I set up my S3 bucket to have a lifecycle policy to delete the objects in the folder? (delete objects in a/ but do not delete 'a' folder)

I have 1 folder in my s3 bucket.

a/

[image: lifecycle policy config]

[image: lifecycle policy config2]

This config was referenced to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52396135/3818748

Comment: It is possible that the folder was never manually created (with the "Create Folder" command, which creates a zero-length object the same name as the folder), so it possibly never 'existing'. Does this really cause you a problem? Why do you need the folder to 'exist'?

Comment: The folder doesn't exist in s3, because in s3 there are no "folders" per se; a better term is to call it a prefix which is a property of the uploaded file. S3 is an object store, not a traditional filesystem. If you upload a file to foo/bar/baz/my.file just the act of uploading to that location brings the prefix of foo/bar/baz in to existence. If there were any rules to prune it, it would work, but only if the prefix exists. Pro tip, do NOT upload a file with a trailing slash in its name....

Comment: Yes, i have created the 'folder' object via terraform. I created the folder to allow my application to upload to that directory. 
if my zero-length object is deleted, will uploading an object that is a child to that zero-length object be still possible?
Eg. mybucket/abc/ and abc/ was a zero-length object and it's deleted. Will uploading to mybucket/abc/helloworld.txt work?